# Blazor Layout conflict with MainLayout

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-routing

So i want a specific page to use another layout and rules but the code initialize of the mainLayout is executed event if the page doesn't use or inherit of it.

`PageWithOtherLayout.razor`

```cs
@layout NoMenuLayout
@page "/pagewithotherlayout"
```

`App.razor`

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
...
```

`MainLayout.razor`

```cs
    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        var user = (await AuthStat).User;
        isAuth = user.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        if (!isAuth)
        {
           NavigationManager.NavigateTo("./login");
        }
    }
```

I didn't find anything usefull but is seem to come from the routing process of blazor.

Comment: Did you find what was causing the issue? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your application you are loading `MainLayout.razor`. If you set the debug launch URL directly to `pagewithotherlayout` you will see that the `OnInitializedAsync` is not called in `MainLayout.razor`.

I just tested this on an empty layout.

**NoMenuLayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="main">    
    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apart from the app.razor the MainLayout is not referred else were for what i see. I test on changing my launch url directly to the page and that still redirect me. Are there others thinks a can tries?

Comment: @joisir is this `.NET6.0`? I can not reproduce

Comment: Yes .Net 6.0 Blazor server